# What are directory permission conventions?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, directory

Running command `ls -l /` shows permissions of directories on my server.

I noticed that most directories are set to `755` or `rwxr-xr-x`, link `bin` and directories `lib`, `lib32`, `lib64`, `libx32` are set to `777` or `rwxrwxrwx`.

`/tmp` uses a sticky bit but others don't. Are the other permissions a security risk? What are conventions regarding these permissions?

Comment: The links are 777, but the underlying directories are 755 as well --> No security risk

Comment: @pLumo Thank you. Could you explain what the function of write permissions are in links?

Comment: Check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487793/symbolic-link-not-inheriting-permissions